# Java reflection API: Invoking a method without parameters

Tags: java, reflection

The method I want to invoke (I know it's public but I need to use reflection):

```
public byte[] myMethod()
```

I get the `Method` object like this and `m` contains `myMethod()` (I checked with the debugger)

```
Method m = Class.forName(MyClass.class.getName()).getDeclaredMethod("myMethod");
```

Finally I need to invoke m and pass the result to an object:

```
byte[] myBytes = null;
m.invoke(myBytes);
```

No exception is thrown but `myBytes` stays null... I also tried the following without more success:

```
m.invoke(myBytes, (Object[])null);
```

How can I get the result of the invocation to myBytes?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> No exception is thrown but myBytes stays null

Correct, what you wanted there was:

```
byte[] myBytes = (byte[])m.invoke(yourInstance);
```

More in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29). Notes:

- The return value of the method is the return value of `invoke`.
- The first argument to `invoke` is the instance on which to call the method (since you've listed an instance method, not a static method; if it were static, the first argument would be `null`). You haven't shown a variable referring to the instance anywhere, so I called it `yourInstance` in the above.

Answer (score 13):

You're currently passing the value of `myBytes` *into* the method - as if it's the target object you'd be calling it on. It's the *return* value.

You want:

```
byte[] myBytes = (byte[]) m.invoke(target);
```

where `target` is the instance you want to call it on (as it's an instance method).

If you don't have an instance, the method will have to be a static method, at which point you'd change the invocation to:

```
byte[] myBytes = (byte[]) m.invoke(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

`invoke` method takes first argument as instance object for the method followed by parameters. 
Here method signature is `public byte[] myMethod()`

Code to invoke `myMethod`:

```
byte[] returnVal = (byte[]) m.invoke(MyClass.newInstance());
```